# How to parse a csv table by value and transform it from 2-row to 4-row table in python?

Tags: python, sql-server, csv

I have this table in .csv with space delimiters:

```
header 1    0   1   2   3
a           0   10  10  10
```

And I need to read it and transform to the following one to further load it to sql format:

```
header 1    header 2   value
a           0          0
a           1          10
a           2          10
a           3          10
```

where "header 2" is constructed from the first row starting from the second value and "value" from the second row. 
I am a new Python user and will appreciate any valuable comment, idea or an example code.

Comment: How did you end up with data in this (difficult to use) format?  Is there any chance you could export your CSV in a better format?

Comment: @DeepSpace it is a single space between each value in fact. I edited the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the problem is that I have a lot of such tables in my data and I cannot transform them manually